# Generating different filenames from unique file in shell script

Tags: regex, perl, bash, shell, variables

I need to execute my evaluateParameters.pl Perl program, for do it, i want to create a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

COVARIANCE=~/Desktop/ncRNA/CovarianceModels/rRNAs_cov/bitscores.rRNA.dat         # First input FILE
BASEPATH='/Desktop/ncRNA/Data/Inputs/rRNAs/60/'

TRUEFILES=~/$BASEPATH/Infernal/*.table                  # Second input File   
CONTROLFILES=~/$BASEPATH/RandomControl/Infernal/*.table # third input file
INPUTFILES=~/$BASEPATH/*.fasta                          # fourth input file   
for i in $COVARIANCE
do
    NAME1=`basename $i`
    for t in $TRUEFILES
    do
        # i.e : 1dvex4_rRNA_cin.out.db.location.fasta.RF00001.cm.tab.table
        NAME=`basename $t`
        echo "Calculating the parameters to $NAME"

        # I need modify $NAME to convert in: 1dvex4_rRNA.cin.out.db.location.fasta
        FILER=$(echo $NAME | sed s/(.*\.fasta)\.(.*\.tab\.table)/\1/g)

        # I need modify $NAME to convert in: 
        # 1dvex4_rRNA.cin.out.db.location.fasta.mutant.fasta.RF00001.cm.tab.table
        FILEM=$(echo $NAME | sed s/(.*\.fasta\.)(.*\.tab\.table)/\1\.mutate\.fasta\2/g)
        perl evaluateParameters.pl $i ~/$BASEPATH/Infernal/$NAME ~/$BASEPATH/RandomControl/Infernal/$FILEM ~/$BASEPATH/$FILER
        echo "END!"
    done
done
```

The last code send me follow warnings:

```
Calculating the parameters to                                 10dvex1_rRNA_ce.out.db.location.fasta.RF00001.cm.tab.table.false.table.false.table.true.table.true.table.true.table .false.table
./obtainParameters.sh: command substitution: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./obtainParameters.sh: command substitution: line 31: `echo $NAME | sed s/(.*\.fasta)\.(.*\.tab\.table)/\1/g'
./obtainParameters.sh: command substitution: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./obtainParameters.sh: command substitution: line 32: `echo $NAME | sed s/(.*\.fasta\.)(.*\.tab\.table)/\1\.mutate\.fasta\2/g'
```

Some ideas? i guess that the error is in the regex on $NAME, but i can't obtain the correct regex result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that hop out at me:

1) your do and done statements don't match (you've got one extra 'done').

2) Put single quotes around your sed expressions; the parentheses are being interpreted as a sub-process by bash.

A good programming text editor with syntax highlighting helps a lot with this.

Comment: But, in this case, $NAME1 represent the firts file name, that do not change. But I am interested in apply a REGEX strategy on $NAME...yes one extra 'done' is present. Thanks! I am using vim.

Comment: Removed note about `$NAME` from answer; I overlooked the definition. If you type `<esc>:syntax on`, you will get syntax highlightin for bash; this showed me the extra `done` highlighted in red.